# Junos Pulse not installing correctly on Yosemite

Tags: macos, install, vpn

I'm trying to set up Junos Pulse so I can connect to a VPN. I got a dmg with the JuniperSetupClientInstaller.mpkg from the Pulse server site, but when I run the installer, it doesn't seem to have any effect. It shows a "Successful Install" message at the end, but nothing seems to have changed. No further windows/dialogs appear, and searching Juniper or Junos doesn't turn up anything new.

I also tried grabbing the installed application from my old computer (running Mavericks), but I get "Failed to connect to the Juniper Unified Network Service." whenever I try to connect to the VPN.

Does anyone have any guidance for either of these approaches? I'm happy to give more information if it would help.

Comment: What is it you are expecting to happen? Did you try to use network in syst pref, then click on the + to add new connection and select VPN ?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD In the first case, I was unable to get to the point where Junos Pulse is an application that I can actually launch and use. In the second case, when I grab the application from my other computer, I go to add a connection from the Junos Pulse app, enter the name and URL for the server (copied exactly from my machine that works) and hit connect or add, both of which give the "Failed to connect to the Juniper Unified Network Service."

Comment: So it is installed but you can not find it? did you read this info? https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2015/03/13/deploying-a-pre-configured-junos-pulse-vpn-client-on-os-x/

Comment: @Buscar웃SD The JuniperSetupClientInstaller claims that the installation succeeded, but I don't have a Junos Pulse app in my Applications folder. Haven't found anything like one by perusing finder either

Comment: I found some installation instructions here: https://vt4help.service-now.com/kb_view.do?sysparm_article=KB0010440

Comment: @Buscar웃SD That matches the process I followed, with the difference that it never prompted me for my password (which may be relevant to the problem). As for the first link, that looks like it's aimed at someone creating a pre-configured setup. I just did a web install

Comment: hmm..did you remove previous VPN as described? Also try changing the  location for the install in the option window.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD There weren't any old VPNs to remove, since I'm installing on a machine I just got today. I don't seem to be getting the option to change the install location (it just skips over that step)

Comment: darn...since it is a .dmg look in the Disk utility to see if they are shown there.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD Ran a "Verify Disk" on the dmg, everything looks ok to DIsk Utility

Answer (score 2):

The way Juniper does this is a little confusing. Installing the **JuniperSetupClientInstaller.mpkg** installer from a Junos Pulse VPN server essentially sets up your machine so that the VPN server can *then* proceed to install Pulse using a Java applet. Here's how the install process works for my shop's Junos Pulse VPN server.

1. Open Firefox
2. Go to the following site:

https://vpn.server.goes.here

3. Log in with your VPN credentials.
4. If prompted by Firefox, allow the Java applet from the VPN site to run.
5. If this is the first time that Junos Pulse has been installed on this Mac, you may be prompted to install the Juniper setup client. If you are not prompted, go to step 6.

   - Click on the **Please click here to install setup client** link.
   - The Juniper setup client will be downloaded in a disk image file.
   - Double-click on the downloaded disk image file to get access to the Juniper setup client installer.
   - Double-click on the Juniper setup client installer and follow the prompts to run the installation process.
   - Once installation of the Juniper setup client has been completed, click on the **Once the setup client is installed, please click here to continue** link.
6. When prompted to install Junos Pulse, click the **Always** button.
7. The Junos Pulse installer will download to your Mac.
8. Once Junos Pulse has downloaded, the Junos Pulse VPN client will be installed on your Mac.
9. Once installation is finished, the Junos Pulse client will automatically connect to the VPN.

Everything in step #5, where the directions are having you install the Juniper setup client, is where the **JuniperSetupClientInstaller.mpkg** installer comes in. It's not the actual VPN installer; it's an installer that preps the machine for the later VPN client installation in steps 6 through 9.

By itself, the **JuniperSetupClientInstaller.mpkg** installer will not install the Junos Pulse VPN client.

Comment: Ah, ok. That helps narrow down the problem, then. I was assuming there was some problem installing the setup client, but it's actually something going wrong in the step 6 area. I'm seeing a "ClassNotFoundException - dsSetupApplet.class"

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue.  The problem was that when attempting to uninstall and reinstall Junos Pulse, there were a few files that were not getting deleted in the Library folder.  However, if you use the built in uninstaller for Junos Pulse, it should get rid of everything.  Then, you can reinstall Junos Pulse and everything works as expected.  Best of luck!